# Can a convection oven be used without exterior venting?

Tags: exhaust-vent

My home is 20 years old. I have a free standing stove/oven and a microwave above installed when home was new. Neither is vented and the roof is tile and exterior is stucco so I won’t be able to vent.

I purchased an LG studio microwave/convection oven and a stove oven/convection. Will I be able to use the convection feature if not vented to the exterior?

Comment: What is stopping you making a hole in the wall for a vent? Been done before...

Comment: 20 years old is faily new, It would seem strange to me, that a microwave vent unit would be installed by the builder without a vent above the oven location.

Comment: Electric, or gas?

Comment: I wasn't aware that a convection oven had any air exchange with the exterior!  Are you **absolutely sure** yours does ?  That would be an incredibly energy-inefficient design.   See mfarver's answer.

Comment: convection ovens do not use a vent ... they have a blower that circulates hot air inside the oven ... that is so that the oven does not have any hot spots

Answer (score 2):

Convection baking uses a fan to circulate air *inside* of the oven.  It does not require a vent to the outside.  You may want a vented range hood to collect smoke and odors from the cooktop, but you do not need one for the oven.

Answer (score 1):

Yes - You can use the Convection feature without a vent.

The Microwave is a vent for the oven. Why are you not installing a vent through the wall?

Install a vent like this:

[image]

My apology,  This new model allows the vent to be recirculating by changing the vent motor orientation.  While not as effective as external venting, it appears to be an acceptable venting solution.  Probably would be acceptable or not acceptable depending on local code.

Comment: Thank You for all the feedback about venting my new appliances...as for not wanting to vent it’s about 5 ft.to exterior wall and the cupboards are there , thanks for pictures we may consider side vent

Comment: The vent would be run in the ceilin; in between the ceiling joists to the exterior wall. the cupboards would not interfer.  The problem may be the joists do not run in the direction you want to go.